# Docker repository does not have a release file for apt-get update on debian bullseye

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt, debian-bullseye

Trying to get an updated / current version of docker on debian bullseye, I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Ign:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bullseye InRelease
Err:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bullseye Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.65.229.91 443]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'docker.list_org' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133455/docker-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-on-running-apt-get-update-on-ubun) article seemed to point in the right direction but I couldn't find anything that worked.

How do I get around this?

Update: Checking the docker repository from the error above,

```
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists
```

I see sub-directories for many other distributions, but no bullseye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official install instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository) the deb URL should be

```
https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable
```

Not `ubuntu`.

Comment: Thanks, just discovered that.  My error, working on two different systems.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to install docker in Linux using the repository:

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

According to docker [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository), I had to replace this `$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")` with the latest stable debian release `bookworm`